# Blank Screen Between ViewController Transition In Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am working on `Hybrid` `Swift` app. For this, I am using `WKWebView`. I wrote code in `ViewDidAppear` to load `HTML` page. Also fetching data from `local DB` to display on the screen. But on every transition on `ViewController` (launching `ViewController` through `NavigationController`), white blank screen appear for few seconds then `HTML` page gets displayed.

**My code is:**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) { 
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "login", withExtension: "html")
    webView!.loadFileURL(fileURL!, allowingReadAccessTo: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
}
```

I want this HTML page should load instantly as `ViewController` launched.

Comment: This is expected behaviour since you load your html in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: try in .     viewdidload

Comment: @ Manish , If I write code in viewdidload, UIView not gets initialize so this HTML page also not display.

Comment: Which UIView can you please elaborate..?

Comment: This code is not working in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

Move the code to viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "login", withExtension: "html")
     webView!.loadFileURL(fileURL!, allowingReadAccessTo: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try by writing this code in ViewDidLoad. Why you don't show loader until page load. And did you set black color for webview.